# Using bindings in Kotlin Script (Jsr 223)

Tags: kotlin, jsr223

I try to follow [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/jsr223-bindings/9556) example to embed a Kotlin Script. But if try to use the bindings map in my script

```
val unit = bindings["unit"] as Entity
```

I get a syntax error (unresolved reference of bindings) and cannot compile the project (in Intellij I created a kts file for the script). How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version on Kotlin you no longer need to use the `bindings` map. Just access it as a normal variable (`unit`).